# Lock custom attributes of an connected app in subscriber organization

Tags: managed-package, oauth2, connected-apps, open-id-connect

I have a connected app (openid connect) that is configured to include custom attributes in the id token. The connected app defines custom attributes (only salesforce standard fields like `$Organization.Id`). The connected app is included in a managed packed. When i install the package in an organization i am able to modify/delete the custom attributes in the subscriber organization.

Note: It seems to be necessary to install/package the connected app. Without installation the custom attributes are not included in the id token for users from organizations other than the organizations where the connected app is stored.

Is there a way to configure/package the connected app/custom attributes in way, so that subscribers are not able to modify the custom attributes?